# Android app wont run in device

Tags: android, mobile

I have an app in development that runs fine in the emulator but wont run on any android device, when the application icon is clicked the screen goes blank for a second then returns back to the device apps page, i have experimented with setting different permissions but it does not seem to solve the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the Logcat running to see if anything is happening?

Comment: i am developing in mono for android and don't have access to logcat

Comment: @sola how have you created your apk file???? if you have created signed apk , make sure that you have saved it with .apk extension